# Change sequence SeqIds in multi-line fasta file

Tags: rename, fasta

I have a multiplex fasta file and I need to change the Ids of my sequence. 
So now my fasta file looks like this:

```
>Mafalda01_2759;barcodelabel=CAR1_01
TACGTAGGGGGCAAGCGTTGTCCGGAATTATTGGGCGTAAAGGGTACGCAGGCGGTTTTTTAAGTCTGATGTGAAATCTC
ATAGCTTAACTATGAGCGGTCATTGGAAACTGGAGAACTTGAGTATAGAAGAGAAGAGTGGAATTCCAAGTGTAGCGGTG
AAATGCGTAGATATTTGGAGGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGACTCTTTGGTCTATTACTGACGCTGAGGTACGAAAGCGTG
GGGAGCAAAC
>Mafalda02_51112;barcodelabel=CAR7_04
TACGTAGGGAGCAAGCGTTGTTCGGATTTACTGGGCGTAAAGGGCGCGTAGGCGGCGCAGTAAGTTACTTGTGAAATCTC
TGGGCTTAACCCAGAACGGCCAAGTAATACTGCAGTGCTAGAGTGCAGAAAGGGCAATCGGAATTCTTGGTGTAGCGGTG
AAATGCGTAGATATCAAGAGGAACACCTGAGGCGAAGGCGGGTTGCTTGTCTGACACTGACGCTGAGGCGCGAAAGCCAG
GGGAGCAAAC
>Mafalda01_145359;barcodelabel=CAC11_86
TACGGAGGATCCAAGCGTTATCCGGAATCATTGGGTTTAAAGGGTCCGTAGGCGGACAATTAAGTCAGCGGTGAAAGTCT
GTAGCTCAACTATAGAACTGCCGTTGATACTGGTTGTCTTGAATCAATGTGAAGTGGCTAGAATATGTGGTGTAGCGGTG
AAATGCTTAGATATCACATAGAACACCGATTGCGAAGGCAGGTCACTAACATTGCATTGACGCTGATGGACGAAAGCGTG
GGGAGCGAAC
>Mafalda02_3119;barcodelabel=CAR4_03
TACGGGGGGTGCGAGCGTTGTCCGGAATCACTGGGCGTAAAGGGCGCGTAGGTGGTCTTATAAGGGTGTGGTGAAAGCCC
GGGGCTCAACCCCGGGTCGGCCGTGCCGACTGTGAGACTAGAGTGCTGTAGGGGCAGGCGGAATTCCGGGTGTAGCGGTG
GAATGCGTAGAGATCCGGAGGAAGACCGGTGGCGAAGGCGGCCTGCTGGGCAGATACTGACACTGAGGCGCGACAGCGTG
GGGAGCAAAC
```

What I want to do is to remove everything up to the sign "=" (except the ">"), remove the "*[number] after the barcode label and add "*[sequencial number]" for each Id of each sequence

Like:

```
>CAR1_1
TACGTAGGGGGCAAGCGTTGTCCGGAATTATTGGGCGTAAAGGGTACGCAGGCGGTTTTTTAAGTCTGATGTGAAATCTC
ATAGCTTAACTATGAGCGGTCATTGGAAACTGGAGAACTTGAGTATAGAAGAGAAGAGTGGAATTCCAAGTGTAGCGGTG
AAATGCGTAGATATTTGGAGGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGACTCTTTGGTCTATTACTGACGCTGAGGTACGAAAGCGTG
GGGAGCAAAC
>CAR7_2
TACGTAGGGAGCAAGCGTTGTTCGGATTTACTGGGCGTAAAGGGCGCGTAGGCGGCGCAGTAAGTTACTTGTGAAATCTC
TGGGCTTAACCCAGAACGGCCAAGTAATACTGCAGTGCTAGAGTGCAGAAAGGGCAATCGGAATTCTTGGTGTAGCGGTG
AAATGCGTAGATATCAAGAGGAACACCTGAGGCGAAGGCGGGTTGCTTGTCTGACACTGACGCTGAGGCGCGAAAGCCAG
GGGAGCAAAC
```

(and so on and so for...)

Would that be possible?

Comment: I apologise for the way I presented the data. Everytime the Seq Id appears it is a new line and always start with ">". The second line is my sequence and after comes a new Seq Id starting with ">" ( introducing a new line)

Comment: Your data is properly formatted now, just format it as code.

Comment: What OS or language do you want to use? There a plenty of options.

Comment: Python probably, because everyone keeps telling me I should learn it. I m just a beginner and I need to improve my basic knowledge. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { c=1 } $1 ~ /^>/ { s=gensub(/.*=([A-Z0-9]+)_[0-9]+$/,">\\1_"c,"g",$1); print s; c+=1 } $1 !~ /^>/ { print }' seqs.fa
```

First, inistalize counter for sequence record:

```
BEGIN { c = 1 }
```

The interesting bit is:

```
$1 ~ /^>/ { s=gensub(/.*=([A-Z0-9]+)_[0-9]+$/,">\\1_"c,"g",$1); print s; c+=1 }
```

`$1 ~ /^>/ { ... }` will only match on lines with leading `>`.

Then, `gensub` captures whatever is after the last `=` into `\\1`, excluding the trailing `_[0-9]+`, then prints `">\\1_"c`, where `c` is value of counter initialized above. Print string `s`, then increment counter.

Second bit of code is:

`$1 !~ /^>/ { print }`

If line does not have a leading `>`, just print it.

Comment: Is there something awk can't accomplish?
But the part which is missing "add "[sequencial number]" for each Id of each sequence". Is there a way to increment the index in awk?

Comment: I have edited the post to correctly address your question.

Comment: FYI, python code posted by @MaximilianPeters is clearly mode legible, as is normal for python vs awk. However, for very large sequence files it may fail as it reads all sequences into memory (I suspect you may have a large file if you are dealing with barcoded sequence data). Awk processes the file line-by-line and will work on large files without issue.  The Python code can be made to read the file line-by-line as well. I guess depends what you want to learn: python or awk. I suggest both! Python for code you want to keep around, and awk for disposable one-liners.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution in Python would be:

```
sequences = """>Mafalda01_2759;barcodelabel=CAR1_01
TACGTAGGGGGCAAGCGTTGTCCGGAATTATTGGGCGTAAAGGGTACGCAGGCGGTTTTTTAAGTCTGATGTGAAATCTC
ATAGCTTAACTATGAGCGGTCATTGGAAACTGGAGAACTTGAGTATAGAAGAGAAGAGTGGAATTCCAAGTGTAGCGGTG
AAATGCGTAGATATTTGGAGGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGACTCTTTGGTCTATTACTGACGCTGAGGTACGAAAGCGTG
GGGAGCAAAC
>Mafalda02_51112;barcodelabel=CAR7_04
TACGTAGGGAGCAAGCGTTGTTCGGATTTACTGGGCGTAAAGGGCGCGTAGGCGGCGCAGTAAGTTACTTGTGAAATCTC
TGGGCTTAACCCAGAACGGCCAAGTAATACTGCAGTGCTAGAGTGCAGAAAGGGCAATCGGAATTCTTGGTGTAGCGGTG
AAATGCGTAGATATCAAGAGGAACACCTGAGGCGAAGGCGGGTTGCTTGTCTGACACTGACGCTGAGGCGCGAAAGCCAG
GGGAGCAAAC
>Mafalda01_145359;barcodelabel=CAC11_86
TACGGAGGATCCAAGCGTTATCCGGAATCATTGGGTTTAAAGGGTCCGTAGGCGGACAATTAAGTCAGCGGTGAAAGTCT
GTAGCTCAACTATAGAACTGCCGTTGATACTGGTTGTCTTGAATCAATGTGAAGTGGCTAGAATATGTGGTGTAGCGGTG
AAATGCTTAGATATCACATAGAACACCGATTGCGAAGGCAGGTCACTAACATTGCATTGACGCTGATGGACGAAAGCGTG
GGGAGCGAAC
>Mafalda02_3119;barcodelabel=CAR4_03
TACGGGGGGTGCGAGCGTTGTCCGGAATCACTGGGCGTAAAGGGCGCGTAGGTGGTCTTATAAGGGTGTGGTGAAAGCCC
GGGGCTCAACCCCGGGTCGGCCGTGCCGACTGTGAGACTAGAGTGCTGTAGGGGCAGGCGGAATTCCGGGTGTAGCGGTG
GAATGCGTAGAGATCCGGAGGAAGACCGGTGGCGAAGGCGGCCTGCTGGGCAGATACTGACACTGAGGCGCGACAGCGTG
GGGAGCAAAC"""

index = 0
for line in sequences.splitlines():
    if line.startswith('>'):
        index += 1
        output = line[line.find('barcodelabel=') + len('barcodelabel='):]
        output = output[:output.find('_') + 1]
        print('>' + output + str(index))
    else:
        print(line)
```

You could [read](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) your sequences from a file and store it in `sequences` or replace `for line in` with

```
fasta_file = open('your_seqs.fasta', 'r')
    for line in fasta_file':
```

The possibilities are endless.....

Comment: Thank you very much. But instead of printing it, I would like to create a new file and write the output in the new file. How can I do that?

Comment: two of many possibilities: `python my_python_program.py > output_file.fasta` or open a file with `f = open('output_file.fasta', 'w')` and instead of print use `f.write(... + '\n')`

Comment: Thank you so much.It worked however, the sign ">" should remain in the Seq Id  and it disappeared.

Comment: Thank you so much. I understood the code now! Thank you!